# Deploying an MVC4 C# application to Azure via GitHub. What should be in my .gitignore?

Tags: c#, git, azure, github, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET, MVC4, C# application which I have developed in Visual Studio 2012. Up to now I have deployed successfully to an Azure website using the VS Publish facility.

I have now successfully set up Git publishing on the Azure Website and linked it with a GitHub repository. I have initialized a repository on my local machine and pushed the whole lot to the GitHub repo. Azure immediately pulled all this as it should.

Now, I was expecting that in the absence of a .gitignore file this wouldn't work perfectly and I was right.

So my question is: **What, from my local Visual Studio working directory should I be omitting from the repository? I.e. what should be in my .gitignore?**

Also, are there any other factors I should be thinking about in trying to get the application working on the Azure Website?

Notes:
1. I had a good look at https://gist.github.com/2589150 but it doesn't seem to tally with what I am seeing in the VS working directory.
2. https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/CSharp.gitignore seems nearer and I am currently working through this trying to understand which bits of it apply to my situation. For example, if I exclude bin/* then the application fails to deploy on Azure.

**UPDATE:**
1) I switched off custom errors by modifying my web.config file as suggested by @levelnis:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I found my problem was the database connection string which was no longer being converted to Azure by the VS Publish facility. I had to modify this directly and commit to the repo.

**Top tip:** I found the correct string by simply looking at what the VS Publish facility put up on Azure by publishing to a temporary Azure website with a different publish profile.

This fixed the problem and the deployment went very smoothly.

2) By this time I had the following as my .gitignore file:

```
    # Build Folders
    obj/

    # User-specific files
    *.user

    # SQL Server files  
    App_Data/*.mdf
    App_Data/*.ldf
```

It seems that I can probably cut out a lot more for tidiness sake, but this was not affecting the correct operation of deploying via GitHub which now actually works extremely smoothly.

Lastly, the handy git command for removing files from the repo without deleting them. A couple of examples:

```
    git rm -r --cached obj/*
    git rm -r --cached */*.user
```

And then obviously add these to .gitignore before adding, committing and pushing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue may not be related to not having a .gitignore file. At worst, you'll be including your compiled dlls in the bin folders within your repository - a really bad idea from a general maintenance perspective but not from a publishing to Azure perspective.

Is the error a Yellow Screen Of Death or simply a blank screen with that message? If it's the latter it sounds as though the deployment failed. You can FTP in to the website and check whether the website files are where they should be. There's also a Logs directory that you'll find there - it may have something that'll help diagnose the error. Here's the .gitignore from my project (yours may need more stuff adding/some bits removing but at least it'll get the dlls out of the way):

```
# git ignore file
_ReSharper.*
[B|b]in/
obj/
*.suo
*.user
```

That isn't Azure specific, it's ASP.NET specific. Incidentally, if you need to remove the dlls and they've been committed, you'll need to add the bin path to .gitignore and delete all the dlls as well

EDIT: add `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` - at least it'll tell you what the error is

Comment: So it's not even getting to your MVC app then? Did you restart the app after deploying? I find myself doing this every time. You can do it from the dashboard in the Azure management portal. Once you've restarted, refresh the browser repeatedly until you a) see a 503 error, b) see that replaced by a 502 error c) refresh again and see the app pool restart. The portal will tell you that it's restarted but it takes about 30-60 seconds for the app pool to actually recycle.

Comment: OK, adding <customErrors mode="Off"/> has helped me a lot. Looks like it's a database issue. Thanks! I'll also post my final .gitignore here once I've refined it as well.

Answer (score 0):

A good example of a gitignore file for Visual Studio is found at the following:

https://gist.github.com/2589150

As for publishing on Azure, I am not versed enough in doing so but I imagine you would find everything you need here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh420322.aspx

And even better, a Microsoft tutorial on publishing with Git to Azure:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-git/

Comment: I had read the 1st reference previously but it didn't seem to match what I was seeing in my VS working directory so I was thinking it didn't really apply to VS2012 and MVC4, etc.and the 2nd isn't git specific but using the publish feature I was already using. Your 3rd reference is exactly the procedure I followed to set it all up.

Comment: 'Error. An error occurred while processing your request.' but nothing more. I am not sure where to look to find more details. I know I need to construct a .gitignore but want to understand exactly the what and the why of what needs ignoring.